# SQL how to count the number of relations between two tables and include zeroes?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, relationship

I have a table of `orders`, and a table of products contained in these orders. (The `products`-table has `order_id`, a foreign key referring to `orders.id`).

I would like to query the number of products contained in each order. However, I also want orders to be contained in the results if they do not contain *any* products at all.

This means that a simple

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) n_products FROM `orders` INNER JOIN `products` on `products.order_id` = `orders.id` GROUP_BY `order_id`
```

does not work, since orders without any products disappear.

Using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead would add rows without product-information, but the distinction between an order with 1 product and an order with 0 products is lost.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do products know their orders, but not the orders their products? Products should be independent from the order...

Comment: @S-Man This is a simplified view of the actual real application, in which the relationship goes through an intermediate many-to-many table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a left join here, and you should be counting some column from the products table:

```
SELECT
    o.*,
    COUNT(p.order_id) AS n_products
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN products p
    ON p.order_id = o.id
GROUP BY
    o.id;
```

Note that I assume that Postgres would allow grouping by `orders.id` and then selecting all columns from that table.  If not, then you would only be able to select `o.id` in addition to the count.

Comment: Aha! So counting a column from the products table, rather than doing `count(*)` would result in a `0` being returned if we have a row from the `orders` table that has no related `products`?

Comment: @Qqwy Yes, because an order with no products would only be a single record with `NULL` in all product columns, and `COUNT` ignores `NULL` and counts them as zero.